# what is uefi? which should i choose between uefi and 8086 for platform id?

Tags: windows, x86-16, uefi

I'm creating an image file (using Imgburn) and there is a section in which i should choose the platform id, and the options are mac,8086 and uefi.
I searched the net for uefi and still I can't realize what to choose or what the differences are.
what is uefi? and which one should i choose between 8086 and uefi?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from Wikipedia about UEFI:

> The interface defined by the EFI specification includes data tables
> that contain platform information, and boot and runtime services that
> are available to the OS loader and OS. UEFI firmware provides several
> technical advantages over a traditional BIOS system:[12]
>
> - Ability to boot from large disks (over 2 TB) with a GUID Partition Table (GPT)[13][a]
> - CPU-independent architecture[a]
> - CPU-independent drivers[a]
> - Flexible pre-OS environment, including network capability
> - Modular design Backward and forward compatibility

So there are some clear advantages.

Now more over to 8086 which is a microprocessor system.

> the 8086 gave rise to the x86 architecture which eventually became
> Intel's most successful line of processors.
>
> As of 2017, the majority of personal computers and laptops sold are
> based on the x86 architecture (despite inroads from Chromebook-style
> ARM designs, the segment-leading Apple MacBook family remains
> exclusively x86), while other categories—especially high-volume mobile
> categories such as smartphones or tablets—are dominated by ARM; at the
> high end, x86 continues to dominate compute-intensive workstation and
> cloud computing segments.[3]

So basically 8086 means you have an processor using the x86 architecture. Which might be but mostly these system are for an datacenter or high end operating machines.

When creating an image it is important to choose the correct architecture since your [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) will be optimized to this architecture. Most common by now is using the UEFI variant.